# Return number-interval to letters in Matlab

Tags: matlab, letters-and-numbers

Is it posible to set up a function in matlab that returns an interval of numbers into a specified letter, i can only make 1=A, 2=B and so on... 
I want a function that can make numbers between 0-10.5=B, 9.5-20.5=X, all the way up till 300 with a new letter each time, is that even possible or do i just have to make the long manual way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a function as:

```
function out = mapNumbers(num)
buckets = [10.5:10:300]; % Create array of the form 10.5 20.5 30.5 ....290.5 
letters = [B X ....]; % You will have to type all letters, there is no way out
idx = find(buckets > num, 1); % find 1st bucket edge > num
out = letters[idx]; % This is the letter the number corresponds to 
end
```

You can tweak with the buckets and find to make it work for your case. Make sure that `buckets > num` really works the  way you define your number to be in a particular bucket (> and >= stuff).

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a nice pattern for your numbers, I believe you're going to have to use a `switch` and hardcode it all in. Saying that, you may be able to have a `case` for a relatively large range, if there are chunks of your number range which do follow the same pattern.